# How to compare someone column from two table and matched record insert into new table?

Tags: mysql

I have clone data based on compare someone column from two tables and matched record data insert into new table? 
some example like

table A and table B are the same structure table but data are different

so how to match  column name(`fieldname`) like(`title`) from those tables and matched record insert into the third table like table C

I have already created the same structured table C, and those three table structure also same

your help appreciated for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
insert into target_table
(target_field)
(select source_column1 as source_column
 from source_table1
          inner join source_table2
                     on source_table1.source_column2 = source_table2.source_column2)
```

if you need to insert unique values, use

```
select distinct source_column1 as source_column ...
```

And you can manage filtration by adding

```
....inner join source_table2
                 on source_table1.source_column2 = source_table2.source_column2
where some_field = "some value"
```